# After upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10, login takes very long

Tags: unity, login, 15.10

After upgrade from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 I noticed, that when I turn on my laptop, it takes few seconds to boot and show the login screen, but the problem appears when I enter my password to login field and press "Enter": the screen shows my desktop image with note "Ubuntu 15.10" in left bottom corner (also I can see my mouse), and it takes about 3-4 minutes until menu bar appears. I know that I login to session immediately, because I can hear skype login sound, it also loads all the startup programs, but I don't understand why it takes so long to show up menu bar.

Does any one have this problem, and may be knows how to solve it?

P.S. my laptop is HP Pavilion dv6-6b04st.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user account and logging in with that? If that is significantly faster it could be some of your stored configuration files that are causing this.

Comment: Ok, I will try that and I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you @Tobias you were right, I created new user account and it took 10-15 seconds to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - empty trash. I checked the trash and saw that it has millions of files and takes 44G disk space. I empty my trash, and problem has gone. So the real problem why ubuntu took so long to login was full trash of small files and it took some time to check them.